# When one div loads, the other div is deleted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

Click here: [henriquecosta.kdhost.eu.org](https://henriquecosta.kdhost.eu.org), type the number 00008513 and choose a radio button and enter, then choose any 8-digit number and type. This part is working wonderfully after so much sacrifice for me, I'm not a programmer. The problem is that when another div is loaded, the previous one is deleted. I need all divs to remain on the page, in all it will be 40 divs. Yesterday I could not resolve with the localstorage, I think it is the solution, after that the script will be finished. Well, I'm happy with what I got so far. If anyone has any tips to give me, I'll be very grateful! Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <--- isto pára o envio da form

  var url = this.action; // <--- o url que processa a form
  var formData = new FormData(this); // <--- os dados da form
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("GET", url, true);
  ajax.onload = function() {
    if (ajax.status == 200) {
      var dados = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
      alert('Dados enviados:\n' + JSON.stringify(dados, null, 4));
    } else {
      alert('Algo falhou...');
    }
  };
  ajax.send(formData);
});

</script>
<form action="index.php">
Cartao:<input size="7" name="cartao" value="" required="" pattern="[0-9]{8}" type="text">
<input value="01" name="armario" type="radio" />01
<input value="02" name="armario" type="radio" />02
<input value="03" name="armario" type="radio" />03
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<table width=100% border=1>
<tbody>
<tr align=center valign="middle">
<td width=33%><div id="01"></div></td>
<td width=33%><div id="02"></div></td>
<td width=33%><div id="03"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<?php
if (isset($_GET['cartao'])):
$radioValue = $_GET['armario'];
$radiovalor = '"'.$radioValue.'"';
$file = 'banco.txt';
$searchfor = $_GET['cartao'];
//header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
            if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)):
            json_encode($matches[0]);
            $resultado = str_replace(array('"',' \r','[', ']'), '', htmlspecialchars(json_encode($matches[0]), ENT_NOQUOTES));  
else:
            $resultado = $_GET['cartao'];
   endif;
        else:
           echo '';
           endif;

// file_exists
if (isset($_GET['cartao'])) {
$path = './fotos/';
$recebe = $_GET['cartao'];
$img = $path.$recebe.".jpg";
if (file_exists($img)) {
          $foto = '"<img width=80 height=80 src="'.$img.'">';                          // existe
} else {  $foto = '&nbsp;&nbsp;<img width=80 height=80 src="./fotos/ausente.jpg">';    // não existe
}
}
?>

<script>
var x = '<?php echo $resultado, $foto; ?>'; 
var z = '<?php echo $radioValue; ?>';
document.getElementById(z).innerHTML += x;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use database...

Comment: Changing the request method in the javascript to GET is still not sufficient or in fact wrong. Your PHP server code still returns a full html page and your JS method is still lacking the return false; statement.

Comment: I'm working on it, thank you, Tobi.

Comment: If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, please mark it as accepted...

Comment: Ok ... I'm waiting for more answers while I research about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code which you are probably not aware of.

First of all, your whole page is reloaded everytime you click the "Enviar" button, because your javascript does not correctly prevent the default action.

To accomplish this, return `false` at the end of the function:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <--- isto pára o envio da form

  var url = this.action; // <--- o url que processa a form
  var formData = new FormData(this); // <--- os dados da form
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("POST", url, true);
  ajax.onload = function() {
    if (ajax.status == 200) {
      var dados = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
      alert('Dados enviados:\n' + JSON.stringify(dados, null, 4));
    } else {
      alert('Algo falhou...');
    }
  };
  ajax.send(formData);
  return false;
});
```

By doing this, the whole page will not be reloaded.

Secondly, your server always returns a full html page, instead of differentiating, whether the url has been accessed by opening the page for the first time or if it received a request from your script.

If `isset($_POST['cartao']` is true, than the request came from your javascript and you should return a JSON object containing the relevant data and build the html in your javascript and append it to your table.

I know that this all sounds a bit confusing if you are not a programmer but I hope I could point you in the right direction.
Once you return a JSON object from your server, I am happy to help you to render HTML from it in javascript.